# Android Pexels Api integration error using retrofit. Getting 404 error

Tags: java, android, retrofit2

I am trying to integrate my application with Pexels API by using Retrofit and GSON but without success. I keep getting 404 error and therefore I am getting a null pointer exception on the console.

This is the working api:
https://api.pexels.com/v1/curated?page=1&per_page=14

```
public class ApiClient {

    public static final String API_KEY = "xxxxxxxxxx";
    public static final String BASE_URL = "https://api.pexels.com/v1/";
    public static Retrofit retrofit = null;


    public static Retrofit getClient(){
        if(retrofit == null) {
            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();
        }
        return retrofit;
    }



}
```

```
public interface ApiInterface {

    @Headers({"Authorization: " + ApiClient.API_KEY})
    @GET("/curated")
    Call<ExplorePageModelResponse>getExplorePagePhotos(
            @Query("page") int page,
            @Query("per_page") int per_page
    );


}
```

This is the service class that communicates with the pexels api. The response body is empty...

```
public class ExplorePageService implements ItemListContract.Model<ExplorePageModelPhotos> {

    private final String TAG = "ExplorePageService";
    private int pageNo = 1;
    private final int PER_PAGE = 14;

    @Override
    public void getExploreItemList(OnFinishedListener<ExplorePageModelPhotos> onFinishedListener, int pageNo) {

        ApiInterface apiService = ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiInterface.class);
        Call<ExplorePageModelResponse> call = apiService.getExplorePagePhotos(1, PER_PAGE);

        call.enqueue(new Callback<ExplorePageModelResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ExplorePageModelResponse> call, Response<ExplorePageModelResponse> response) {

                List<ExplorePageModelPhotos> list = response.body().getExplorePageModelPhotos();

                onFinishedListener.onFinished(list);

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ExplorePageModelResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.e(TAG, t.toString());
                onFinishedListener.onFailure(t);

            }
        });


    }

}
```

This is the api response:

Response{protocol=h2, code=404, message=, url=https://api.pexels.com/curated?page=1&per_page=14}

I must be doing something wrong in the ApiInterface part since it's all working on the postman side but couldn't figure out. Thanks.

Comment: Remove `/` from `@GET("/curated")` just write `@GET("curated")`

Comment: If i do that the url becomes this:  https://api.pexels.com/curated/?page=1&per_page=14

Comment: So basically when I write `@GET("curated")` I get `/`to the end for some reason. If I put the `/` to the beginning of curated then `v1` gets deleted.